# Is it possible to change order of divs (not just aesthetically) ONLY when certain browser width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have HTML like:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

But when `@media (min-width: 890px) and (max-width: 958px)`, I want to have it like:

```
<div class="inner">
    <div class="outer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?
If so, how would I achieve it?

Comment: Do you want to reorder for styles?

Comment: Reorder from style is not possible. You have to use javascript/jquery for this purpose

Comment: jQuery from a template I'm using breaks styles at certain browser widths unless divs are in different order in the HTML.  OK, I am looking into JS solution

Comment: I think you might not approach the problem in the right way. HTML should be used for describing the content of your page, and CSS for styling it. The width of the viewport should not change the content of your page, so your HTML should not need to be reordered. 
If you need to switch the position of different elements, you should look into the order property of flexbox and css grid. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Javascript for this.

[.matchMedia()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_matchmedia.asp) serves as our `@media` query.

```
const x = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 890px) and (max-width: 958px)');

function mediaQuery(x) {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        const first = document.querySelector(".outer");
        const second = document.querySelector(".inner");
        first.className = "inner";
        second.className = "outer";
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
}

mediaQuery(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```css
.outer > .inner {
  // some style
}

@media (min-width: 890px) and (max-width: 958px) {
  .inner > .outer {
    // some style
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inner outer">
  <div class="inner outer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the `order` property
like this

```css
div#myRedDIV   {order: 2;}
div#myBlueDIV  {order: 4;}
div#myGreenDIV {order: 1;}
div#myPinkDIV  {order: 3;}

@media (max-width: 600px){
  div#myRedDIV   {order: 4;}
  div#myBlueDIV  {order: 2;}
  div#myGreenDIV {order: 3;}
  div#myPinkDIV  {order: 1;}
}

#main {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
}

#main div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;" id="myRedDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;" id="myBlueDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;" id="myGreenDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;" id="myPinkDIV"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No...you can't. You can't use `order` to change parent & child.